# Как сделать ОДНО слово в тексте ссылкой?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно ОДНО слово в тексте сделать ссылкой.
Вот так:
Перейти на [сайт](https://www.google.com/).

Кидать в конструктор ссылки отдельными элементами не комильфо - текст большой. Можно ли использовать linkArea и тогда как?

C#. Windows Forms. Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать компонент [`LinkLabel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1).

1. Добавьте на форму компонент `LinkLabel`
2. Задайте ему текст «Перейти на сайт»

   ```
   linkLabel1.Text = "Перейти на сайт";
   ```
3. Задайте область ссылки: 4 символа, начиная с 11-го.

   ```
   linkLabel1.LinkArea = new LinkArea(11, 4);
   ```
4. Обработайте событие `LinkClicked`. В нем откройте нужный адрес

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
     //говорим ОС, чтобы в новом процессе открылся адрес
     //ожидается что при этом будет запущен браузер по умолчанию.
     Process.Start("https://www.google.com/");
}
```

Если ссылок несколько, то нужно будет работать со свойством [`Links`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.links?view=netcore-3.1) задавать каждой ссылке адрес и обрабатывать его в `LinkClicked`

Comment: Могли бы Вы написать про несколько ссылок? VS ругается, что "LinkLabel.Link является тип, но используется как переменная".

Comment: @maps По [ссылке, которую я дал в ответе](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.links?view=netcore-3.1), есть пример кода как раз с двумя ссылками.